# Wrong Total Processes in Ganglia

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ganglia

I have *ganglia 3.6.0* installed in *Ubuntu 14.04(trusty)* but the number of total processes is greater than when I run `ps -efa | wc -l`, for example ganglia total processes metric show me **500 total** process now, but in terminal I only see **170 total** process, anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may try comparing it to `ps -eLfa | wc -l` (add `-L`) which will include all threads in `ps` output.